# Can multiple layers of nested callbacks when saving be avoided in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections, the first with an array of id's referencing documents in the second collection.

There is a particular place where I want to create a new `DocumentType`, then a new `Document` that references that `DocumentType` and finally update the original `DocumentType` to reference the new `Document`.

A `DocumentType` can have many `Documents` but a `Document` can only have a single `DocumentType`. The reason why I want to have the reference in both places is to simplify more complex queries later on.

My question is: is there a better way to write it using mongoose than to have these mulitple nested callbacks.

I've put together a simple example to demonstrate. There is more data in the real thing and as such I don't want to have `Document`s embedded in `DocumentType`s or visa versa.

```
var DocumentTypeSchema = new Schema({
    name:   String
  , desc:   String
  , documents:  [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Document'}]
  , ...
});

var DocumentSchema = new Schema({
    title:    String
  , doctype:  {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'DocumentType'}
  , ...
});

var Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema);
var DocumentType = mongoose.model('DocumentType', DocumentTypeSchema);

// Begin the nested callbacks
// Create a document type
var type = new DocumentType({...});

// Save document type
type.save(function(err) {

  // Create new document
  var document = new Document({
      doctype: type.id
    , ...
  });

  // Save document
  document.save(function(err) {

    // Update document type
    DocumentType.update({_id: document.doctype}, {'$addToSet': {documents: document.id}}, function(err) {});
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that there generally is not a better way for synchronous processing. The `series` function of the `async` library mentioned by Jani is a fine way to flatten this, but I think it's generally a good idea to stick with the callback structure – it makes the scoping very clear and reduces your external dependencies – unless the nesting gets to be absurd or you need async. Your nesting is not absurd, though you might consider [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) going forward. If you're creating two new instances and saving attributes across both, there's no reason to do the creation synchronously. Instead, something like this:

```
    async.parallel({
        type: function(callback) {
            var type = new DocumentType({...});
            type.save(function(err) {callback(null, type)});
        },
        document: function(callback) {
            var document = new Document({...});
            document.save(function(err) {callback(null, document)});
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        results.document.doctype = results.type.id;
        results.document.save();
        DocumentType.update(
          {_id: results.type},
          {'$addToSet': {documents: results.document.id}},
          function(err) {}
        );
    });
```

It requires an extra save, and frankly may be silly for a task like this with so little performance overhead, but it illustrates a good approach for async processing and the versatility of the async library.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'll keep this in mind. Asynchronous logic is a shift in thinking that I'm still getting used to!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like node-async's `series` function to run each of the callbacks after each other. This way you don't have to nest them.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll definitely use this in more complex situations